# iptables разрешить подключение по 3389 с любой машины

Tags: linux, iptables

Я использую скрипт NETBLCOKER для блокировки всех исходящих соединений кроме, соединений к VPN серверам. Скрипт https://zorrovpn.com/static/download/netblocker.sh . Но после его старта становится невозможным управлять машиной по xrdp по порту 3389. Какое правило iptables нужно добавить в скрипт чтобы разрешить подключение к данной машине по 3389. Подключение может быть и из локальной сети и также через переадресацию портов из вне

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo iptables -t table1 -A INPUT -p xrdp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Что такое table1 ?

Comment: Также ошибка unknown protocol "xrdp" specified

Comment: @Андрей `table1` это таблица с правилами. по поводу ошибки, проверьте `netstat -nlpt`, должны работать `xrdp` и `sesman-xrdp`.  ещё стоит посмотреть сообщения при перезапуске сервиса и логи